# Can operator>> read an int hex AND decimal?

Tags: c++, hex, istringstream

Can I persuade `operator>>` in C++ to read both a `hex` value AND and a `decimal` value?  The following program demonstrates how reading hex goes wrong.  I'd like the same `istringstream` to be able to read both `hex` and `decimal`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int result = 0;
    // std::istringstream is("5"); // this works
    std::istringstream is("0x5"); // this fails

    while ( is.good() ) {
        if ( is.peek() != EOF )
            is >> result;
        else
            break;
    }

    if ( is.fail() )
        std::cout << "failed to read string" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "successfully read string" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "result: " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`std::setbase(0)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase) which enables prefix dependent parsing. It will be able to parse `10` (dec) as 10 decimal, `0x10` (hex) as 16 decimal and `010` (octal) as 8 decimal.

```
#include <iomanip>
is >> std::setbase(0) >> result;
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to tell C++ what your base is going to be.

Want to parse a hex number?  Change your "is >> result" line to:

```
is >> std::hex >> result;
```

Putting a std::dec indicates decimal numbers, std::oct indicates octal.

Answer (score -2):

0x is C/C++ specific prefix. A hex number is just digits like a decimal one.
You'll need to check for presence of those characters then parse appropriately.